# Including a different version of a library, in a maven dependency totally broke my build

Tags: maven, jackson, versioning, spring-social

So I had

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <scope>${defaultScope}</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I included this

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

which itself includes this

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Which resulted in a no class not found for jsonwrapper.

I updated my original version of jackson dependency to be up-to-date with the spring-social included version, and it now works.

This seem rather fragile/unfriendly, is there something I should be doing to avoid such problems ?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the dependencies of dependencies using

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

In your case it yelds:

```
+- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile
|     \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
\- org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
   +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
   +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
   |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
   |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   \- org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
      \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

And as far as I see, it's not `spring-social-web` that includes `jackson-mapper-asl`

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Maven to ignore transitive dependencies using `<exclusions>` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>org.codehaus.jackson</artifactId>
            <groupId>jackson-mapper-asl</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

With this definition Maven will use only dependency that you defined earlier (1.8.3 version). But be aware that sometimes this can lead to other problems, for example spring-social-web may use features that do not exist in 1.8.3 version.